# Number of Concurrent pipeline Execution config

Tags: spinnaker

Have been looking at Spinnaker code to see where the MAX value for the number of concurrent pipeline execution is defined. 
Closest I found was `new JedisPipelineStack("PIPELINE_QUEUE", jedisPool)` in OrcaPersistenceConfiguration.groovy. And I'm trying to find the configmap  for Orca.Any pointers?